# How make ExtJS grid responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs6

How make ExtJS grid responsive. That would grid stretched across the width of the browser window. Thanks!

```js
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    height: 200,
    width: '100%',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```